# Scan an array of strings and group them by most frequent characters/words (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I have a bunch of strings that I want to organize. Currently, I manually check them and group them based on words I can see within the strings, however, I want to see if it can be done with a PHP script. For example, if my list contains 100 or so strings like "fungames" or "funnychat" I would group those together as they both contain the word "fun" (and make sure each string is only used once across all the string/word groups).

So, let's say you have an `array('gaming','game', 'fun', 'fungames')`, this will then need to be organized into different groups by the most frequently found words/strings. **We don't know what words/strings to match against**, so we need to do check against the strings until we find matches. Plus, the strings don't have any spaces between words (making it much more complex I imagine). Am I also right in imagining that this would take significant time when you need to process say 1,000 strings with much more variety in them?

An example output from my above example array might be:

```
'gaming'=>[
    'gaming',
],
'game'=>[
    'game',
    'fungames',
],
```

In the above example output, it won't display 'fun' as a new category to group by because the 'fun' string was already used in a previous group's array set. Also, priority is given to longer strings (as it would capture more complete "words" rather than the "ing" from "gaming" being split up. Additionally, it will aim to avoid creating small groups but try to group strings together as much as possible (e.g. it won't just add "fungames" as it's own group, then "fun" as another group).

I understand if this is too complex - I am happy to do things manually if need be BUT it would be very interesting to me to see this done programmatically!

Comment: It would be interesting, sure, but I fear you didn't choose enough rules to have a consistent result, for example what is the minimum number of letters for it to be a word (or is "e" a category)? How to ensure it is an existing word (or can "gaming" and "reading" be classed as "ing")? The rules "priority given to longer strings" and "not in new category because used in a previous group" can be contradictory: what happens if "fun" is found first? One possible solution is to limit yourself to strings existing in your array as the categories, or effectively you need more rules.

Comment: Ah, you're right. This question needs more thought to it. I'd actually suggest min letters to be 1, since languages will have words with only 1 letter! Even in English, the letters A and I are words. As for the contradictions that are possible, well, I'd say a running order would suffice. We should prioritise the uniqueness of the words in each category group first, then, longer strings. Limiting to strings to those existing within the arrays should work, but it won't have as great of a result and would be too limiting.